# Функция, которая возвращает сумму и разность элементов(язык Си)

Tags: c, функции, указатели

Необходимо написать функцию, которая возвращает сумму и разность двух элементов(не используя структуры). 
Программу необходимо написать именно через return. С помощью указателей, у самого не выходит, можете помочь?

Comment: И в чём проблема?

Comment: Ну верните через указатели, что сложного?

Comment: Вот именно что я пока не могу понять тему с указателями, как будет выглядеть код?

Answer (score 1):

```
void f(int a, int b, int*sum, int*dif)
{
    *sum = a+b;
    *dif = a-b;
}

...

int s, d;
f(5,3,&s,&d);
printf("5+3 = %d, 5-3 = %d\n",s,d);
```

Comment: Нужно именно через return, такое возможно?

Comment: И без структур? ну разве что упаковать два значения `int` в одно `long long`...